# Django unable delete form with data shown

Tags: python, django, forms

i have created a delete function for my forms but it can only delete if i did not display out my information.

However if i try to display the information out on the delete page, the delete function wouldn't work.

i think because when i display the information out, the form isn't valid, hence unable to delete the object.

My views.py

```
def servicing_entry_delete(request, serv_entry_id):
delete_object = get_object_or_404(serv_entry, id=serv_entry_id)


if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Delete_Flying_form(request.POST, instance=delete_object)
    if form.is_valid():  # checks CSRF
        delete_object.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reversed('hello:servicing_entry'))  # wherever to go after deleting
else:
    form = Delete_Flying_form(instance=delete_object)

return render(request, 'hello/servicing_entry_delete.html', {'form':form})
```

My forms.py

```
class Delete_Flying_form(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = serv_entry
    fields = ('Servicing_Type', 'Time', 'Date','Ic_Clear_Name','Ic_Clear_Time','Ic_Clear_Date')
```

My deleteconfirmation.html

```
{% extends 'hello/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Delete Servicing Entry</h1>

<p>Are you sure you want to delete this Entry: </p>
{{ form }}

<form action="" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="submit" action="" value="Yes, delete this Entry." />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Without the {{ form }}, i am able to delete the object smoothly but not being able to display any information.

However if i try to display, like this
[image: Help, with the display of information, i cannot delete]

is there anyway if i could display this few fields and still delete successfully?
My django version is 1.11
with python 2.7.5

Much appreciate!

Comment: I don't understand why you want all those fields in a delete form. Surely you just want to display the object data, not edit it.

Comment: Hmm but how do i display the data without having fields in the delete form?

Comment: Same way you'd display it on any non-form page.

Comment: I tried with the same way to display out those form values but for this i can't, not sure why tho